# The change event - Is there a way to differentiate between User change and programmatic change?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I need to execute some code in my `ViewController` only when a field in the `View` has its value changed by the user, triggering the `change` event.

The problem is that in some places in the controller, I'm using `this.getViewModel().set('name', 'value')` which also triggers `change`. In these cases, where the value is changed programmatically, I don't want to execute the code which is triggered by the event. `suspendEvents()` doesn't work, it seems [there's a bug](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?171525-suspendEvents-did-not-affect-to-Ext.app.Controller.control) which didn't get fixed since a very long time. (It says [FIXED] but people still complain that it doesn't work).

So is there a way to detect whether this change was made by me (programmatically) or by the user?

I'm using ExtJS 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Your view could fire a custom event which would separate your user change from the programmatic one.

It would be easier to help, if you can provide a short runnable example on Sencha Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There's a private property in the [Field mixin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-property-suspendCheckChange) which is used internally to avoid firing the `change` event.
It's a numeric flag, so setting it to 1 should do it. Based in the mixin, you could do something like:

```
me.suspendCheckChange++;
this.getViewModel().set('name', 'value')
me.suspendCheckChange--;
```